# iCloud Music Library can't be enabled

Tags: ios, apple-music

I downloaded iOS 8.4 this morning, and activated Apple Music. I started browsing, and found an album I wanted to add to my library. When I tried to add it, I was told that I needed to enable iCloud Music Library, and was directed to the settings.

[image] [image]

However, when I try to enable it in the settings, I get an error saying that "iCloud Music Library can't be enabled". No further details are available. This error occurs whether I choose to "Merge" or "Replace" my device's current library.

What do I need to do to get past this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keep trying. After toggling the setting to enable it a dozen times over twenty minutes, it finally worked. This appears to have been a temporary problem associated with the launch.

Comment: Turning airplane mode on then off worked for me.

Comment: Just keep trying. It worked on my 30th attempt. As others have mentioned, Apple is probably getting slammed with people activating their free trial to Apple Music.

Comment: I rebooted the phone and it worked.

Comment: Turn on and off airplane mode ... It worked for me

Answer (score 4):

From [iMore](http://www.imore.com/getting-icloud-music-library-cant-be-enabled-error-heres-fix)

> 1. Launch Settings from the Home screen.
> 2. Tap Music (note, the icon has changed colors).
> 3. Toggle iCloud Music Library to On.
> 4. Choose if you want to Replace or Merge your library. (I ultimately chose Merge when it worked).
> 5. If you get the error again, dismiss it.
> 6. Repeat steps 3-4 until it works.

[image: settings]

Answer (score 0):

### Wait until tomorrow.

There are millions of people trying to enable, signing up and "force retrying" to activate Apple Music at the same time; from Apple's point of view this probably looks as a [DDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack).