# Can't sign up for Apple Music

Tags: ios, apple-music

When trying to set up Apple Music on my daughters iPhone we get a message saying "Sorry, we've found a problem that prevents us signing you up for Apple Music at this time. We expect to have it fixed in a few days..."

[image: screen shot]

Two other family members have set it up with no problems.

IPhone 5 is the "faulty one" (others that work are iP5 and 6). All are running iOS 8.4

We have family sharing set up, each of us have separate Apple IDs (all linked to the same credit card).
Does anyone have any suggestions of how we may get this to work now (rather than just waiting?)

One clue may be that my daughter is the only one of us that has ever had an iTunes Match account (2 years ago, now lapsed)

Comment: This isn't a question but a statement of an issue you are having, if the question is: Why – that is unknown Apple Music is days old. If the question is what should I do: the error message states that this is something Apple is working on, you will need to wait a few days. If the issue persists after two weeks I would suggest contacting AppleCare. However you've not asked a question, so it's not easy to answer this.

Comment: what is the device and the IOS difference ?

Comment: IPhone 5 is the "faulty one" (others that work are iP5 and 6). All are running iOS 8.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet it is because she had iTunes Match. My father and I are both having the same problem and both of us has iTunes Match, but no one else is having problems with it.

Comment: I know of 4 accounts that paid for iTunes Match and none had this issue.

Comment: Just for info,we tried again today and it all worked ok, so I have no idea what Apple have been doing, but it seems they have fixed it (for my daughter anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think contacting Apple Support is going to help much, but you can always give that a shot.

Clearly the error message acknowledges a known (to them) issue and a response saying you need to wait *days* for them to have a fix.

Initially I heard mostly from UK and other EU users so I guessed perhaps Apple needs to cleaning up those accounts. I don't think this anymore since it looks like some portion of people across the globe are being delayed.

Each user that signs up for Apple Music causes server load:

- CPU and network bandwidth is needed to communicate with their devices
- Each user uses storage and has to have their preferences recorded and playlists generated for each user (or at least linked to their accounts)
- Each user's iTunes library needs to be ingested and stored online

If Apple has a temporary capacity issue, code scaling issue, or their model for how many people would sign up were too conservative then it might take days to spin up more servers or test and deploy the code change.

I've heard one person try to make a new Apple ID. I'd strongly recommend to **not make a new Apple ID** unless you are prepared for even more confusion or clean up later. If you're desperate to try the new hotness this weekend,  you can always open a support ticket with Apple or if you feel this error message shouldn't apply to your account.

My guess is this is an evolution of this error with an explanation that you don't need to do anything other than wait a day or so...

- [iCloud Music Library can't be enabled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193734/icloud-music-library-cant-be-enabled)

You may have to pay for support if AppleCare don't see this as something that's in their scope of free support (recent purchase, paid AppleCare or just free to ask for anyone):

- https://www.apple.com/support/music/

Look for an updated FAQ and articles or use the "Contact Us" link on the left if this drags on past your patience in the matter. I hope the delay is short for anyone wanting in on the service.